# would you help me how to change the order of data set on xmgrace?

Tags: xmgrace

I've been trying to find a way how to change the order of data on xmgrace.

Let's say on my dat file, my data is

`x dx y dy` instead of `x y dx dy`. So, how can I change and set this order on xmgrace? I mean I think I could do it using evaluate exp but it takes too long time. Is there any easy and fast way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Hello and welcome to stack overflow!

If I understand correctly, you have a datafile with 4 columns, but they are not in the x, y, dx, dy order. However, you want to plot them as they were. If this is the case, you can use xmgrace's command-line options like this

`xmgrace -settype xydxdy -block data.dat -bxy 1:3:2:4`

Note that the order of the options is *very* important, since `-block` (which specifies the datafile) should come before `-bxy` (which specifies which columns should be used, and in what order), and `-settype` (which, unsurprisingly, specifies the type of the set) should also come before `-bxy`.

Comment: Thanks! However, whenever i tried, it says cant stat file input.dat no block data. I have no clue

Comment: Does "xmgrace input.dat" work? The error you report is usually associated with a wrong file name.

Comment: The command I used is exactly "xmgrace input.dat", and it worked but when I tried " xmgrace -settype xydxdy -block input.dat -bxy 1:3:2:4",  it says cant stat file input.dat no block data

Comment: Well, this is really bizarre, as the same command works fine for me.